# Can I use VBA to click the Cancel button?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Message box that comes up whenever I click the close button to close Excel window. The message is "This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue?" There is an ongoing refresh process that stays for almost an hour, but if I click the Cancel button, everything happens in less than 2 minutes. Is there a way to click the cancel button with VBA?

I really need the pop up to show, so I don't need to turn `Application.DisplayAlert = False`. Any help will be appreciated.

I'm trying to refresh Power queries in the Workbook using VBA. These queries source data from csv files in a folder. I've been using two methods with serious issues

1. The first approach does not complete before moving to the next line of code. This results in an a workbook that's not completely updated before it's saved.

   ```vb
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   ```
2. The second code seems to be the popular solution to the first, but it lasts for almost an hour. This code refreshes each query one after the other. Note: "Enable Refresh in Background" is turned Off. I've spent weeks hunting for information to make this method work faster but no solution:

   ```vb
   For Each objConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
       'Get current background-refresh value
       bBackground = objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery

       'Temporarily disable background-refresh
       objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False

       If Left(objConnection.Name, 8) = "Query - " Then
           Cname = objConnection.Name
           'Show the Query name that's being updated in the Status bar
           Application.StatusBar = "Refreshing ... " & Cname
       End If

       'Refresh this connection
       objConnection.Refresh

       'Set background-refresh value back to original value
       'objConnection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = bBackground
   Next
   ```

   The only way I make it faster now is to manually click Close button in Excel window while the `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll` is running and then click Cancel in the pop up.

I need to know if it's possible click the Cancel button with VBA.

Comment: That is a fun behaviour to research and/or submit as a bug report.

Comment: Please share some code related to this ongoing refresh process.

Comment: It depends... I mean, if the Message box in discussion occurs after `Workbook_BeforeClose` event, you can try something (using API functions ans Spy++ or a similar application to find the button handler). If not, you must find the root of the problem. Do you have some add-ins installed? If yes, I would disable each of them, step by step, until you (may) find the problematic one. But, do you have any function call in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event? If yes, you can simple comment that line and solve the problem...

Comment: Do you have [ScreenUpdating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating) set to `False` in your macro?

Comment: I have tested with  ScreenUpdating set to False

Comment: `does not complete before moving to the next line of code` - do you have Enable Refresh in Background turned off at the point where you call `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`?

Comment: No I didn't. I only turned it off directly on Connection Properties in Excel. Am I supposed to turn it off with VBA be fore .RefreshAll. How is that done?

Comment: If you turn it off in the connection properties and save the file, you don't need to do it at all, but the the question is why you are doing it with the method 2. Turn them all off, save the file, open it again and try ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll.